# Is this a geometry nodes bug or not ? Mesh To Curve node behaviour on 3.6

Tags: geometry-nodes

Notice the difference in behavior between Blender 3.5.1 and 3.6.1, please.

In the latter, split edges are merged into the one spline.
Is this correct behavior?

It's a big difference so it might be a known topic, but let me ask just in case.

[test with same file↓]

I created a simple curve that has six control points.
then I use it in a geometry nodes on a default plane.

3.5.1[image: 3.5.1 behaviour]

3.6.1[image: 3.6.1 behaviour]

Simple WA in this case
[image: WorkAround]

Comment: Since Blender has to actively merge the vertices in a way to create one spline instead of 5, I would not necessarily think that it is a bug, because it's not like the splitting does not work or something like that, the parts are in fact separate before converted back to curve. The question would be, why was this changed - and this makes me wonder is there now in 3.6.1 a method in _Geometry Nodes _to split segments of a spline into several splines with each only having two control points?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand what you are saying. If there is any chance that this is not a bug I will wait for more information around me. (I haven't fully perused the official resources ...... ).
In the simplest case, I think a Separate Geometry node or something like that would be a tentative workaround, I'm sure there are better ways.

Comment: Well, the problem is a _Separate Geometry_ node does not split splines into individual segments...

Comment: I can't think of any way that this behaviour is desirable. It's semantically inconsistent, _Merge By Distance_   is available to perform the weld, should you want it .. and yet, as Gordon says, it seems too deliberate to be a mistake. Maybe you should post your workaround as an answer, to be tidy. I think this _should_ be a bug report, if only to provoke an explanation.

Comment: Known bug: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/109236

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments.
I couldn't find the bug information on my own, so I am very grateful to you for providing the information. By the way, it is also reproduced in 4.0α, so I hope it will be fixed soon.